# How to return first 10 nodes ordered by created time together with the number of their out edges

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j to model my data. I have two resources: posts and comments. Every post may have edges pointing to several comments, meaning that the comments are under this post.

Now I want to display the post list to the users, so I have to fetch the posts ordered by created at. Meanwhile, I also need to return the comment number under those posts.

Could anyone tell me how to implement it in Neo4j with Cypher, effectively?

I tried

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:COMMENT]->(c:Comment) 
RETURN id(p), count(c)
ORDER BY p.created_at
SKIP 10
LIMIT 10;
```

But received an error:

```
SyntaxException: Unknown identifier `p`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using a `WITH` clause followed by an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:COMMENT]->(c:Comment)
WITH p AS post, count(c) AS numberOfComments 
ORDER BY post.created_at
RETURN id(post), numberOfComments
LIMIT 10
```

The `MATCH` speaks for itself, the `WITH` clause assigns some values to the variables `post` and `numberOfComments` that in turn can be constrained by an optional `ORDER BY` clause before the final `RETURN` clause. The `LIMIT 10` limits the results to the first ten posts.

You can also put the `ORDER BY` clause after `RETURN`, but you still need the `WITH` clause:

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:COMMENT]->(c:Comment)
WITH p AS post, count(c) AS numberOfComments 
RETURN id(post), numberOfComments
ORDER BY post.created_at
LIMIT 10
```

Note that you probably don't want the `SKIP 10` clause, because it will skip the actual ten first posts, so then your result would start at the eleventh post and be limited up until the twentieth post.

Comment: Thanks:) But I am not sure if such query is fast. In my test db, there are 27,500 posts and each have 10 comments on average. Then such query cost 1800ms on average. I am using MacBook Air with i5 CPU. Is it too slow?...

Comment: @HanXu I'm no expert when it comes to performance, but depending on the application you're developing, it might or might not be slow. Do you have any [indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-schema-index.html) set up? That might speed up things. I don't know of any better ways. This answer should solve the problem you asked for though.